# Using the JOIN function

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm new to MySQL and am trying to learn more about the JOIN function.

Let's say I have the following code and I want to find the count for each level of 
the variable and then join the two column.
So the data looks like:

```
in_clicks:
one
one
one
two 
three
four
four 
four 
four
four
five 
five
six
seven
seven
seven
eight
```

and I'm trying to generate the following output:

```
four    5
one     3
seven   3
five    2
two     1
three   1
six     1
eight   1
```

Not knowing anything about the JOIN function, I can use something similar to the following code to get my desired result. (it doesn't work)

```
SELECT(SELECT * FROM in_clicks) AS keys,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM in_clicks) AS KeysNum;
```

However, how can I use the JOIN function to optimize my sql code?

Comment: I don't believe you could do that with a join, a join is designed to connect data from multiple tables.

Comment: @mazzzzz Actually, self-joins are possible (i.e. table joining with itself). This is not what is needed here though - a simple GROUP BY is enough, as explained by cdhowie.

Comment: `JOIN` is a relation *operator* rather than a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a join here at all.  Assuming that `number` is the column you have listed:

```
SELECT number, COUNT(number)
FROM in_clicks
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC
```

The [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregate function basically counts the number of rows.  (`COUNT(*)` would have worked just as well.)  The magic here is [`GROUP BY number`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/), which instructs the database to group the results by distinct values of `number`; the aggregate functions will evaluate each group separately.  Since there are five rows in the "four" group, `COUNT()` over that group will yield 5.

Selecting the `number` column is possible because we have grouped by it; without `GROUP BY number` we could not<sup>*</sup> select `number` alongside of an aggregate, since that wouldn't make sense.  Selecting this column allows you to see which group the corresponding aggregate result belongs to.

And the `ORDER BY` clause should be self-explanatory... sort the results descending by the count of rows in that group.  Note that the order of rows whose counts are the same is unspecified; you can do `ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC, number ASC` if you want to order first by the count descending, then the `number` column ascending... but note that it will be a text comparison, so the order would be four, one, seven, five, eight, six, three, two.  If you order only by the count then the relative order of the one/seven and two/three/six/eight rows will not be reliable, since they have equal counts.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> *Actually it* is *possible in MySQL to select non-aggregated columns that are not included in GROUP BY, but this is non-standard and should be used with utmost caution. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)*.</sub>

Comment: Good answer, you almost always need a group by with aggregates.